# How to extend C# class

Tags: c#, .net

I have got code something like

```
IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> mentions = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline();
RecentTweetList.ItemsSource = mentions;
```

What I want to do is to add somehow to **TwitterStatus** 1 extra attribute to convert **CreatedDate** of that class to get minutes. *(I cannot redesign TwitterStatus.)*

So I guessed to do like:

```
public class NewTwitterStatus : TwitterStatus
{
        public string MinAgo 
        {
            get 
            {
                TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(base.CreatedDate);
                return diff.Minutes.ToString() + "m";
            }
        }
}
```

**But I cannot figure out how to do the cast?**

```
IEnumerable<NewTwitterStatus > mentions = (????)service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline();
```

---

Thank you all of you guys!

**THE SOLUTION (based on Chris' suggestion):**

```
IEnumerable<NewTwitterStatus> mentions = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline().Select(x => new NewTwitterStatus(x));
RecentTweetList.ItemsSource = mentions;



 public class NewTwitterStatus
    {
        TwitterStatus Data { set; get; }

        public NewTwitterStatus(TwitterStatus ts)
        {
            Data = ts;
            ts = null;
        }

        public string ProfileImageUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return Data.User.ProfileImageUrl;
            }
        }


        public string ScreenName
        {
            get
            {
                return Data.User.ScreenName;
            }
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return Data.User.Name;
            }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {                
                return Data.Text;
            }
        }

        public string MinAgo 
        {
            get 
            {
                TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(Data.CreatedDate);
                int mins = diff.Minutes * -1;

                if (mins < 60)
                    return mins.ToString() + "m";
                else  
                {
                    double h = mins / 60;
                    double m = mins % 60;
                    return h.ToString()  + "h " + m.ToString() + "m";
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you thought about adding an extension method to TwitterStatus?

Comment: Is `service.ListTweets..` a method you control or do you simply use it?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram  Yes. I simple use it.

Comment: Why can't you add an extension method?  You'd be in control of it.  It doesn't get added directly to TwitterStatus, so you wouldn't be modifying TwitterStatus.

Comment: Why not?  Extension methods are perfect for this scenario.  If they are not suitable, can you explain why?  Or do you need an example of how they would apply here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can't do an extension method then I would make your `NewTwitterStatus` class have a constructor that takes a `TwitterStatus` to allow easy conversion and then use some linq like the following:

```
IEnumerable<NewTwitterStatus > mentions = 
    service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline().Select(x=> new NewTwitterStatus(x));
```

This will basically take the original IEnumberable and map the elements into the new type. Its a bit less elegant than an extension method but should do the trick.

Comment: +1 You just described the decorator pattern in conjunction with a Linq projection - decorator would have been the only option before extension methods came around :)

Comment: Ah yes. I hadn't even thought of it in terms of the decorator pattern. Though I believe decorators don't usually implement new methods so much as just modifying existing ones (so their entire interface looks identical). Not sure if that is a hard and fast rule though.

Comment: You could be right about that, my understanding was that *Decorator* added extra functions while *Wrapper* modified existing ones, I guess there's a fair amount of crossover in either case..

Answer (score 9):

You cannot extend a class this way - the `TwitterStatus` instances that you receive simply do not have the property you want. One workaround would be to use an extension method:

```
public static class TwitterExtensions
{
    public static string MinutesAgo(this TwitterStatus status)
    {
        TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(status.CreatedDate);
        return diff.Minutes.ToString() + "m";
    }
}
```

Now you could just call the `MinutesAgo()` method on your `TwitterStatus` instances:

```
foreach(var status in mentions)
{
   string howManyMinutesAgo = status.MinutesAgo();
}
```

**Edit:**

You should be able to use extension methods - another approach would be copying the `TwitterStatus` properties to your extended class using a mapping tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) - this would allow you to data-bind on your extend class instances using your custom properties. This is a lot of extra work though (computationally, not for coding usually), so I would not recommend it if you are able to use extension methods instead:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TwitterStatus, NewTwitterStatus>();
IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> mentions = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline();
IEnumerable<NewTwitterStatus> extendedMentions = mentions.Select(x=> Mapper.Map<NewTwitterStatus>(x));
```

Comment: Beat me to it and +1 because I think this is the way to go here.

Comment: Cool! But how do I later will use RecentTweetList.ItemsSource = mentions; ?  Because I have to use MinutesAgo() in XAML template.

Comment: Why don't you use XAML Converter instead of extending the binding entity?

Comment: @DmitryBoyko:the above code will make it look like TwitterStatus has the "MinutesAgo" method on it as long as the TwitterExtensions class is in an included namespace.

Answer (score 5):

You can not cast a base class to a sub class.

You have several options (in order of recommendation)

1. Extension Method
2. [Decorator Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9364251/80274)
3. Partial Classes
4. Implicit conversion

I really recommend option 1, but I list the other two for learning experiences.

---

### [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Extentension methods require you to make a static public class in your project, then from within a static method you pass in `this DataType whateer` this will allow you to call your function without modifying the class, this is how LINQ works.

```
public static class ExtensionClasses
{
    public static string MinAgo(this TwitterStatus status)
    {
        TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(status.CreatedDate);
        return diff.Minutes.ToString() + "m";
    }
}

//Use
{
    IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> mentions = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline();
    foreach(var mention in mentions)
    {
        var minAgo = mention.MinAgo();
        //Do somthing with minAgo
    }
}
```

---

### [Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

To use a partial class you use the keyword `partial` in your class declaration. There are some restrictions on when you can use it (and likely not be able to in your case). See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for details.

```
public partial class TwitterStatus
{
        public string MinAgo 
        {
            get 
            {
                TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(this.CreatedDate);
                return diff.Minutes.ToString() + "m";
            }
        }
}


//Use
{
    IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> mentions = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline();
    foreach(var mention in mentions)
    {
        var minAgo = mention.MinAgo;
        //Do somthing with minAgo
    }
}
```

---

### [Implicit Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)

A Implicit conversion is the step you did not include in your original example in your question.

```
//This code is untested and not gaunteed to work,
public class NewTwitterStatus
{
    private NewTwitterStatus(TwitterStatus twitterStatus)
    {
        this.twitterStatus = twitterStatus;
    }

    private TwitterStatus twitterStatus

    public string MinAgo 
    {
        get 
        {
            TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(base.CreatedDate);
            return diff.Minutes.ToString() + "m";
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator NewTwitterStatus(TwitterStatus status)
    {
        return new NewTwitterStatus(status);
    }

    public static implicit operator TwitterStatus(NewTwitterStatus status)
    {
        return status.twitterStatus;
    }

    //You will need to do this for ever function/Member in TwitterStatus
    public bool SomeFuncFromTwitterStatus()
    {
        return this.twitterStatus.SomeFuncFromTwitterStatus();
    }
}


//Use
{
    IEnumerable<NewTwitterStatus> mentions = service.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline();
    foreach(var mention in mentions)
    {
        var minAgo = mention.MinAgo();
        //Do somthing with minAgo
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea but unfortunately this won't work as the OP doesn't have control over the TwitterStatus type (thus cannot make it a partial class)

Comment: @MattDavey That's why I mentioned the restrictions, Check the new version it lists a lot more options.

Comment: Agree with your other options - however the partial class idea is totally moot. As partial class implementations can only exist in the same assembly - if this were possible he would have to have the source code to `TwitterStatus` - meaning he could just add the property directly. Anyhoo, +1 for the effort on this answer :)